# Intuition behind modular arithmetic $21z \equiv 3 \mod 16 \iff 5z \equiv 3 \mod 16$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm learning modular arithmetic and find the following simplification counter-intuitive.

$21z \equiv 3 \mod 16 \iff 5z \equiv 3 \mod 16$

Of course it's not hard to prove this from scratch:

$$\forall z\; s.t. 21z \equiv 3 \mod 16 \iff \exists k\; s.t. 21z=3+16k \iff 5z=3+16(k-z) \iff 5z \equiv 3 \mod 16$$

However, by counter-intuitive I mean I failed to find this simplification stated explicitly throughout the textbook. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @gotit--thanks So we can substitute all numbers in the LHS with its $\mod 16$, wherever it appears?

Comment: @gotit--thanks Great. Thanks. Can you move it to the answer panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way modular numbers work.

Given you're working in $\text{mod} 16$, you can pretend there are only $16$ different numbers (technically, there are $16$ different *equivalence classes*, but for simplicity let's just call them numbers).  We can label them $$0,1,2,\dots, 14,15$$  But this isn't the only way to label them.  In fact each different number has an infinite number of *pseudonyms*.  For instance, $0\equiv 16\equiv 32 \equiv -16\mod 16$, where $\equiv$ means that the LHS and RHS are just different names for the same number.

The different *names* for each of the numbers can be found by adding (or subtracting) some multiple of $16$ to each one.  For instance, $4\equiv 20 \equiv -108\mod 16$, because $20=(1)\cdot 16+4$ and $-108=(-8)\cdot 16 +20 = (-7)\cdot 16 +4$.

So you can see that because $5 \equiv 21 \mod 16$, (almost) everywhere you see a $21$ you can just replace it by the number $5$.

---

Also notice that the $\text{mod} 16$ doesn't just apply to the RHS of the equivalence, it's actually applying to the entire thing.  So, $$\begin{align}21z &\equiv 5z \mod 16 \\ \text{means }\ \ \  (21z &\equiv 5z) \mod 16 \\ \text{NOT }\ \ \  21z &\equiv (5z\mod 16)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $21z\equiv 3\pmod{16}$; then $21z-3=16k$, for some integer $k$. Therefore
$$
5z-3=16z+5z-3-16z=16k-16z=16(k-z)
$$
and so $5z\equiv3\pmod{16}$.

The converse is almost the same and you should be able to supply it.

In a more abstract way: when you have $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{n}$, then $(a+c)\equiv(b+d)\pmod{n}$ and $ac\equiv bd\pmod{n}$.

Since $16\equiv0\pmod{16}$ and, of course, $z\equiv z\pmod{16}$, we have $16z\equiv 0z\pmod{16}$; thus
$$
21z\equiv 5z+16z\equiv 5z+0\equiv 5z\pmod{16}
$$
Since congruence modulo $n$ is transitive, saying $21z\equiv3$ is exactly the same as saying $5z\equiv 3$ (modulo $16$).

What's the “intuition”? You can add (or subtract) at will multiples of $16$, when considering congruences modulo $16$.